# Vaadin 7 PasswordField regex validation not working

Tags: java, regex, vaadin, vaadin7

For standard Java regular expressions working fine as:-

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("space here");
    Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher("noSpaceHere");
    boolean foundSpace = matcher.find();
    boolean noSpace = matcher.find();
    System.out.println("Space found "+foundSpace);
    System.out.println("Any space found "+noSpace);
```

I assumed it should be same for Vaadin. But it is not working:

```
PasswordField field = new PasswordField((String) processConfig.get("name"));
field.setWidth("100%");
field.addValidator(new RegexpValidator("\\s", "Whitespace is not allowed for password field"));
```

Screenshot:-
[image]

Whatever input I give to this PasswordField field it always reports invalid. In this case, I gave "abcd" as input. My intention is not to allow any whitespace for the password field. How to do it for Vaadin PasswordField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try regexpt that allows 0-n of any other character except white space:

```
field.addValidator(new RegexpValidator("[^\\s]*", "Whitespace is not allowed for password field"));
```